# Is there a way to reference data that's within Visual Studio, but is in a different file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, right now I'm working on a mapping project. All the data I have is static, but will eventually be turned into a service. I don't want all the data to be in my main file because it takes up to much space, and is too time consuming to get to the actual code. I want to put the data into it's own file within the project, but I can't get it to reference back the data in the main project. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Any code you have would be helpful

Comment: How do you "reference" the data and how does that fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx). These allow you to include data in your project that is not source code. You can reference back to those resources via properties of a generated `Resources` class.